# The convergence of the series $\sum (-1)^n \frac{n}{n+1}$ and the value of its sum

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

This sum seems convergent, but how to find its precise  value? 
$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}{(-1)^{n+1} \frac{n}{n+1}} = \frac{1}{2}-\frac{2}{3}+\frac{3}{4}-\frac{4}{5}+...=-0.3068... $$ Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Why do you think it seems convergent?

Comment: Have you  noticed that the terms don't go to $0$?

Comment: @FredeF Despite what people are telling you, the sum does converge. Let me write up a solution.

Comment: @Bob1123 This sum only approaches $-0.3068$ when you ignore all the partial sums where $n$ is odd.  The series you are describing is not the one written in the question.

Comment: I see. But when taking the terms two at a time, the series is conditionally convergent. This explains how the sum seems convergent but isn't.

Comment: @Bob1123 Taking the terms two at a time, the series consists only of negative terms, so it cannot be conditionally convergent (it is in fact absolutely convergent).

Comment: @Bob1123 The series becomes conditionally convergent when you subtract it from the similar series $1 - 1 + 1 - 1 + \cdots$ (which sum to $0$ when taking two terms at a time but is otherwise divergent).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is true that since the partial sums do not approach a single limit, the series does not converge. The partial sums instead hover around two numbers, accumulating at one after adding every even term, and accumulating at the other after adding every odd term, and thus alternating between the two. Lets find out what these two accumulation points are.

Taking the even partial sum,

$$\lim_{m\rightarrow \infty} \sum_{n=1}^{2m} (-1)^{n+1} \frac{n}{n+1}$$
$$=\lim_{m\rightarrow \infty} \sum_{n=1}^{m} (-1)^{2n} \frac{2n-1}{2n} + (-1)^{2n+1} \frac{2n}{2n+1}$$
$$=\lim_{m\rightarrow \infty} \sum_{n=1}^{m} \frac{2n-1}{2n} - \frac{2n}{2n+1}$$
$$=\lim_{m\rightarrow \infty} \sum_{n=1}^{m} \frac{(2n-1)(2n+1)-(2n)^2}{(2n)(2n+1)}$$
$$=\lim_{m\rightarrow \infty} \sum_{n=1}^{m} \frac{-1}{(2n)(2n+1)}$$
$$=\lim_{m\rightarrow \infty} \sum_{n=1}^{m} -\frac{1}{2n}+\frac{1}{2n+1}$$
$$=\lim_{m\rightarrow \infty} \sum_{n=2}^{2m} \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n}$$
$$=\lim_{m\rightarrow \infty} -1 + \sum_{n=1}^{2m} \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n}$$
$$=-1 + \ln 2$$

At first I split up the sum between even and odd terms, and then was able to add them back together later. That last sum is the alternating harmonic series, which is conditionally convergent, a consequence that is implied by the others' answers. This constant $\ln 2 -1$ is the number that you think the series converges to. But because the absolute value of the terms tends towards $1$, the series actually alternates between $\ln 2$ and $\ln2 -1$ when you consider the odd partial sums. So while the series does not converge, manipulation show that a different form of it could conditionally converge. That's why you always have to compute the partial sums as well.

Answer (score 3):

The limit of the terms of the sum is not zero, thus it does not converge.

This is a well known theorem in calculus. If you are unfamiliar with it, you can nevertheless understand it intuitively: if the terms don't eventually all become very close to zero, then the sum is either getting arbitrarily large (if all the terms are the same sign) or the sum is jumping around (if the terms are alternating, which they are in this case).

Comment: thanks! So there will always be miniscule fluctuations, even though the value of the sum becomes more and more stable for a given precision (i.e. decimal number)?

Comment: ... but on the other hand, the larger n is, the closer the n/(n+1) gets to 1, while the next term will tend to -1. So in the limit, the value will be +1-1=0, no?

Comment: @FredeF The value of your sum does not become more and more stable, it exhibits large fluctuations every time.  You might be mistaking it for the sum $\sum_n ( \frac{2n-1}{2n} - \frac{2n}{2n+1})$, which does converge.

Comment: It isn't true, that the limit is 0. Consider the series: 1-1+1-1+1-1..., if you say the limit is $0$, let us see the same series this way: 1-(1+1)-(1+1)..., in this case, the limit is $1$, and that is a contradiction with the uniqueness of the limit, therefore, there is no limit at all.

Comment: @FredeF This is the limit of individual terms, not of the sum of two consecutive ones. You are right that eventually the sum will essentially be fluctuating between two values because, as you say, +1-1=0. But a limit needs to be stable around one value.

Comment: @Atvin I don't see how that's a rearrangement, you have one positive $1$ and the rest are negative $1$s. Do you mean $1 - (1-1) - (1-1)$?

Comment: Yeah you are right, but in that case, the limit is $1$, and $1 \ne 0$, thanks for correcting. :)

Comment: @FredeF Also, the fluctuations are not "miniscule" as you say in your first comment. In fact, as $n \to \infty$, the terms become greater in absolute value. If for example we had $\frac{1}{n+1}$ instead of $\frac{n}{n+1}$ then the series would converge as you say because the fluctuations become more stable.

Comment: @Soke True, thanks. Is it then possible to determine the two stable points in the limit?

Comment: @FredeF yes, it is.

Comment: @FredeF This wil be its lim superior and lim inferior. Make another question if you wish to know how.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** This series can't converge, since |$a_n| \rightarrow 0$ is not true, because $\frac{n}{n+1}=1$, if $n \rightarrow \infty$(This is a neccessary term).

Answer (score 1):

Be a little more careful. You can see that the limit of each term goes to $1$. With the alternator thrown in there, you essentially have the sum $$1-1+1-1\ldots$$ for large enough $n$. For a sum to be convergent you need $$\lim_{n \to \infty}a_n = 0$$